# Configure postfix to send and receive to and from localhost

Tags: postfix

Does anyone know what needs to be configured for postfix so that emails can be sent to localhost and received from localhost?

**e.g.** send an email to user1@localhost will:

- result in user1 receiving an email in their mail client (configured to receive local emails)
- user1 can then respond to user2@localhost
- Both user1 and user2 are configured on the same machine i.e. if there is no internet/network connection both these users can still send and receive to/from each other.

The reason I ask is because I want to set this up for a dev environment so that I can test an application I am developing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file like this one:

```
myorigin = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
relayhost =
```

Short explanation of the parameters:

- [myorigin](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myorigin):
  this is the host name that the postfix program will use when
  sending email.
- [mydestination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination): 
  this is the host name(s) that the postfix server
  considers itself able to receive mail for - you want `localhost` and
  any hostname on the machine (look into `/etc/hosts`) to be listed
  here.
- [mynetworks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks)
  lists the "trusted" IP addresses from which postfix accepts *any*
  email
- [relayhost](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost): if not empty, postfix will forward all emails to this
  server for delivery; you want this to be empty for local delivery to
  work.

You might want to have a look at
http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html
for a more authoritative explanation.

Comment: This worked on our rhel 5.8 servers, but we had to use our DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Should I change mynetwork if I am using oopendkim?